# And Design Table TypeScript getColumnSearchProps example

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, antd

i'm using the following ant component : https://ant.design/components/table/
and i'm really struggling to add the following search option in my table :
[image]
here's the table i've created so far :
[image]

i'm pretty new to both React and Typescript , since the project is not in js but in typescript i cannot get my code to work properly looking at ant documentation ; i've turned my component to a functional component as i'm gonna be using hooks and added some code to get out most of the compiler errors (type declaration for ts) , still have some syntax errors :

heres my code:

```
import React,  { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

// @ts-ignore
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';

//**External Libraries */
//REACT MOSAIC
import {ExpandButton, MosaicWindow, RemoveButton} from "react-mosaic-component";
import {MosaicBranch} from "react-mosaic-component/src/types";

//BLUEPRINTJS
import {InputGroup} from "@blueprintjs/core";

//ANTDESIGN
import { Table , Button  ,Tag , Input , Space} from "antd";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; // or 'antd/dist/antd.less'
import {CaretRightOutlined , SearchOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';

//STYLES
import './styles.css'

//API
import {useGetAllUtenti} from '../../../api/index';
import { Utente } from '../../../api/types';

const  UserSummaryWindow: React.FC<any> = (props) => {

  //HOOKS STATE FOR TABLE SEARCH
  const [searchText , setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [searchedColumn , setSearchedColumn] = useState('');

  const {path} = props;

  const dataSource: Object | any = useGetAllUtenti().data;

  const ruoli: any = [
    {
      text: 'User',
      value: 'user',
    },
    {
      text: 'Administrator',
      value: 'administrator',
    },
    {
      text: 'NumeroVerde',
      value: 'numeroVerde',
    },
  ]

  const stati: any = [
    {
      text: 'Attivo',
      value: 1,
    },
    {
      text: 'Non Attivo',
      value: 0,
    }
  ]

  const columns: any = [

    {
      title: 'Nome',
      dataIndex: 'nome',
      key: 'nome',
      defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
      sorter: (a:any, b:any) => { return a.nome.localeCompare(b.nome)},
    },
    {
      title: 'Cognome',
      dataIndex: 'cognome',
      key: 'cognome',
      sorter: (a:any, b:any) => { return a.cognome.localeCompare(b.cognome)},
    },
    {
      title: 'Ruolo',
      dataIndex: 'ruolo',
      key: 'ruolo',
      filters: ruoli,
      onFilter: (value:any, record:any) => record.ruolo.indexOf(value) === 0,
      sorter: (a:any, b:any) => { return a.ruolo.localeCompare(b.ruolo)},
      render: (text: string) => (
        <>        
          {
                <Tag color={renderTagColor(text)}>
                  {text.toUpperCase()}
                </Tag>
          }
        </>)
    },
    {
      title: 'Gestore',
      dataIndex: 'gestore',
      key: 'gestore',
      sorter: (a:any, b:any) => { return a.gestore.localeCompare(b.gestore)},
    },
    {
      title: 'Username',
      dataIndex: 'username',
      key: 'username',
      sorter: (a:any, b:any) => { return a.username.localeCompare(b.username)},
    },
    // {
    //   title: 'Password',
    //   dataIndex: 'password',
    //   key: 'password',
    // },
    // {
    //   title: 'IDEnte',
    //   dataIndex: 'idEnte',
    //   key: 'idEnte',
    // },
    {
      title: 'Tipo',
      dataIndex: 'tipo',
      key: 'tipo',
      sorter: (a:any, b:any) => a.tipo - b.tipo,
    },
    {
      title: 'Stato',
      dataIndex: 'stato',
      key: 'stato',
      filters: stati,
      onFilter: (value:any, record:any) => record.stato.indexOf(value) === 0,
      sorter: (a:any, b:any) => a.stato - b.stato,
      render :(stato: number) => (
        <>
          {
            (stato == 1) ? 
              (
                <Tag color="#00cc00">
                  Attivo
                </Tag>
              ) :
              (
                <Tag color="#ff0000">
                  Non Attivo
                </Tag>
              ) 
          }
        </>)
    },
    {
      title: 'Ultimo aggiornamento password',
      dataIndex: 'ultimoAggiornamentoPassword',
      key: 'ultimoAggiornamentoPassword',
      sorter: (a:any, b:any) => a.ultimoAggiornamentoPassword.localeCompare(b.ultimoAggiornamentoPassword)
    },
    {
      title: '',
      dataIndex: 'idUtente',
      key: 'idUtente',
      render: () => (
        //da inserire link per andare al dettaglio / modifica utente
        <Button type="primary"><CaretRightOutlined /></Button>  
      ),
    },
  ]

  const toolbarControls = React.Children.toArray([
    <ExpandButton/>,
    <RemoveButton/>
  ]);

  function renderTagColor(text:string): string {
    switch(text) {
      case 'user':
        return 'gold';
      case 'administrator':
        return 'red';
      case 'numeroVerde':
        return 'green';
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }

  getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={node => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
      }
    },
    render: (text:string) =>
      searchText === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text.toString()}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      ),
  });

  function handleSearch (selectedKeys:any, confirm:any, dataIndex:any) {
    confirm();
    setSearchText(selectedKeys[0]);
    setSearchedColumn(dataIndex);
  };

  function handleReset (clearFilters:any) {
    clearFilters();
    setSearchText('');
  };

  return (
    <MosaicWindow<string>
      title="Riepilogo Utenti"
      path={path}
      toolbarControls={toolbarControls}
    >
      <Table 
      dataSource={dataSource} 
      columns={columns} 
      bordered={true}
      //pagination={{ pageSize:3,position: ['bottomCenter'] }}
      pagination={{position: ['bottomCenter'] }}
      rowKey={'idUtente'}
      //stile per righe striped
      rowClassName={(record, index) => index % 2 === 0 ? 'table-row-light' :  'table-row-dark'}
      />
    </MosaicWindow>
  );
};


export default UserSummaryWindow;
```

The part which is giving me headeache is (need to convert it to typescript [strict option in config file is enabled]):

```
getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={node => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
            Reset
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
      }
    },
    render: (text:string) =>
      searchText === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text.toString()}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      ),
  });
```

I'm not here asking you to correct my code , just wanted to know if anyone could share a typescript implementation of that getColumnSearchProps function , or an example of the table component from ant design with typescript code..

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution to it?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for such a late reply, i was having the same problem.
I found the solution on a github repo someone made. i really wonder why the antd devs don't support typescript in these days.
anyways, here is the repo.

https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-react-antd-table-search-column-demo

Basically All the hardwork of moving the old JS code to typescript is done, although there are some linting errors here and there.

I hope anyone who comes looking for this answer really questions their decision to use antd instead of react-table or material-design.

Comment: ... `use antd instead of react-table or material-design.` totally agree with u :)
thx for sharing the repo, saved me lot's of frustration ))

Answer (score 3):

Same answer as Lav Hinsu, but I'll paste the full code here, just in case that link dies.

```js
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Table, Button, Input } from "antd";
import { ColumnType } from "antd/lib/table";

function tableColumnTextFilterConfig<T>(): ColumnType<T> {
  const searchInputHolder: { current: Input | null } = { current: null };

  return {
    filterDropdown: ({
      setSelectedKeys,
      selectedKeys,
      confirm,
      clearFilters,
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={(node) => {
            searchInputHolder.current = node;
          }}
          placeholder="Search"
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])
          }
          onPressEnter={() => confirm()}
          style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
        />
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => confirm()}
          icon={<SearchOutlined />}
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 90, marginRight: 8 }}
        >
          Search
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" style={{ width: 90 }} onClick={clearFilters}>
          Reset
        </Button>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: (filtered) => (
      <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => searchInputHolder.current?.select());
      }
    },
  };
}

type Data = {
  key: string;
  name: string;
};

const data: Data[] = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Jim Green",
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
  },
];

function Hello() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Table
        columns={[
          {
            title: "Name",
            dataIndex: "name",
            render: (text: string) => text,
            ...tableColumnTextFilterConfig<Data>(),
            onFilter: (value, record) => {
              return record.name
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(value.toString().toLowerCase());
            },
          },
        ]}
        dataSource={data}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.body);
```

In short, you can just extract the `tableColumnTextFilterConfig` function and implement the `onFilter` property on the desired column.